# Image Control Smaller Than Image Size

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have an image control that is displaying a logo on the page.  The image is 500 x 500 pixels, but when this appears on screen the control shrinks it down to 19x20.    I can't figure out how to override any CSS that is setting this smaller size, or how to generally make it bigger.   If I use Google Chrome, Inspect and then edit the attributes I can see that it should be fine, I just can't get it to run properly.

Here are some code snippets from my site:

ASPX:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" Height="500" Width="500" CssClass="logoImage" ImageAlign="Middle" />  <p></p>
```

The CSS I'm using is:

```
logoImage {
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
}
```

The generated mark-up is:

```
<img id="mainContentPlaceHolder_imgLogo" class="logoImage" skindid="btnCSV" src="../App_Themes/Main/images/logo.gif" align="middle" style="height:19px;width:20px;">
```

The image URL is set in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition is missing a dot. Also try adding `!important` attribute:

```
.logoImage {
   width: 500px !important;
   height: 500px !important;
}
```

But do try find out where that `height:19px;width:20px` comes from (maybe from `mainContentPlaceHolder` size or from in-code assignment).